# Align <dl> <dt> <dd> to center of the page

Tags: html

Any way to align the   to the center of the page. Tried align center but i guess wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Set a width and then set `margin: 0 auto;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ktdvx/)**